# JQuery Browser doesn't reload image having a usemap

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I am using an imagemap (with the ImageMapster plugin) to let users hover over certain parts of an image, which then shows a larger version of it with extra info.

I then want to be able to show other parts of the image which requires a different point of view. I do this by letting the user go to the next image, which is an image of the person slightly rotated, to create a kind of "3D-effect". I do this by letting the user click on an arrow or by using the arrow-keys on their keyboard (without the imagemap). I do this by changing the image's src attribute and adding a timestamp so that the browser reloads the image.

But then the problem arises: if I change the src of an image having an imagemap, the browser doesn't reload the image, nor with the timestamp. I checked the source of the page and the src attribute changes correctly.

The HTML:

```
<img id="test" src="image1.jpg" usemap="#map1" />
<map name="map1">
 <area shape="poly" coords="...." href="#" />
</map>
```

The JS:

```
function showPicture(){
  var newImg = "image"+newindex+".jpg";
  $("#test").removeAttr("usemap");
  $("#test").attr("usemap", "#imgmap"+newindex);
  $("#test").removeAttr("src");
  $("#test").attr("src", newImg+"?" + new Date().getTime());
}
```

The image does reload if I remove the usemap attribute, but not if I add a (different) imagemap afterwards. I tried changing the imagemap after the new image is done loading (so in the load() functionality), but this doesn't make the browser reload either.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found the problem, I had to unbind and rebind ImageMapster to the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, I had to unbind and rebind ImageMapster to the image